# How to make the text from a Plain Text a String(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I am making this app, and in the design part, I Placed a Plain Text, the Id is TEXT1,
and I want the String A to be equal to what ever the user place in the Plain Text(TEXT1),
but it doesn't work...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        final Text TEXT1=(Text)findViewById(R.id.TEXT1);
        final Button TRANSLATE=(Button)findViewById(R.id.TRANSLATE);
        TRADUCIR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String A;
                A=(Text)findViewById(TEXT1);   // ERROR IS IN HERE!

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), A,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Also, don't use UPPERCASE FOR LOCAL VARIABLES NOR FOR LAYOUT IDS, IT'S NOT PART OF THE ANDROID/JAVA CONVENTION AND IT LOOKS LIKE THIS. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Text`, you probably meant to use `TextView`.

And to get its contents, use `getText()`, i.e.

```
String text = (TextView)findViewById(TEXT1).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Instead of `A=(Text)findViewById(TEXT1);`

Answer (score 0):

You must replace Text by TextView and use this :

```
A = TEXT1.getText().toString();
```

instead of this :

```
A=(Text)findViewById(TEXT1);
```